# Send one report to each manager using VBA and Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, email, outlook

I have a list which contains:
- Clients 
- Manager e-mail
- Head manager e-mail

I'm trying to send e-mails using VBA and Outlook, in a way that each time the loop finds one manager (I'm checking for an e-mail address), it sends every client listed for that manager.

If a branch has no manager e-mail address listed, the e-mail should go to the Head Manager (branch 1236, for example, would receive one e-mail, to the Head Manager, with several clients).

The e-mail body will contain pre formatted text, and after that the sheet list with the client list.

I'm having some troubles:

a) to list the branch's clients from the sheet to the mail body
b) to jump from the next manager after the first e-mail, instead of repeating the e-mail for the same manager every time the loop finds the same manager
c) logging the mail sent on the J column

This is a sheet with some of the report:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qo-DceY8exXLVR7uts3YU6cKT_OOGJ21/view?usp=sharing

My loop works somewhat, but I believe I need some other approach to achieve this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'envia o email com registro de log

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim emailformatado As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim destinatario As String
    Dim comcopia As String
    Dim assunto As String
   'Dim body_ As String
    Dim anexo As String
    Dim corpodoemail As String
   'Dim publicoalvo As String

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   'Loop para verificar se o e-mail irá para o gerente da carteira ou para o gerente geral
    For Each cell In Sheets("publico").Range("H2:H2000").Cells

        If cell.Row <> 0 Then
            If cell.Value <> "" Then                   'Verifica se carteira possui gerente.
                destinatario = cell.Value              'Email do gerente da carteira.
            Else
                destinatario = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'Email do Gerente Geral.
            End If
            assunto = Sheets("CAPA").Range("F8").Value 'Assunto do e-mail, conforme CAPA.
           'publicoalvo = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
           'body_ = Sheets("CAPA").Range("D2").Value
            corpodoemail = Sheets("CAPA").Range("F11").Value & "<br><br>" & _
            Sheets("CAPA").Range("F13").Value & "<br><br>" ' & _
            Sheets("CAPA").Range("F7").Value & "<br><br><br>"
           'comcopia = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value         'Caso necessário, adaptar para enviar email com cópia.
           'anexo = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value            'Caso necessário, adaptar para incluir anexo ao email.

           'Montagem e envio dos emails.
            Set emailformatado = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            With emailformatado
                .To = destinatario
               '.CC = comcopia
                .Subject = assunto
                .HTMLBody = corpodoemail '& publicoalvo
                '.Attachments.Add anexo
                '.Display
            End With
            emailformatado.Send
            Sheets("publico").Range("J2").Value = "enviado"
        End If
    Next

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a manager class that has a collection of clients. Have a collection of manager instances.

```
Manager Class
'@Folder("VBAProject")
Option Explicit

Private Type TManager
    ManagerEmail As String
    Clients As Collection
End Type
Private this As TManager


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Clients = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set this.Clients = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get ManagerEmail() As String
    ManagerEmail = this.ManagerEmail
End Property
Public Property Let ManagerEmail(ByVal value As String)
    this.ManagerEmail = value
End Property
Public Property Get Clients() As Collection
    Set Clients = this.Clients
End Property

Client Class
'@Folder("VBAProject")
Option Explicit

Private Type TClient
    ClientID As String
End Type
Private this As TClient

Public Property Get ClientID() As String
    ClientID = this.ClientID
End Property
Public Property Let ClientID(ByVal value As String)
    this.ClientID = value
End Property

Standard Module
Option Explicit
Dim Managers As Collection
Sub PopulateManagers()
    Set Managers = New Collection
    Dim currWS As Worksheet
    Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("publico")
    With currWS
        Dim loopRange As Range
        Set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 8)) 'H2 to the last used row; assuming it's the column for manager emails
    End With
    Dim currCell As Range
    For Each currCell In loopRange
        If currCell.value = vbNullString Then 'no manager; try for a head manager
            If currCell.Offset(0, 1).value = vbNullString Then 'no managers at all
                Dim currManagerEmail As String
                currManagerEmail = "NoManagerFound"
            Else
                currManagerEmail = currCell.Offset(0, 1).Text
            End If
        Else
            currManagerEmail = currCell.Text
        End If
        Dim currManager As Manager
        Set currManager = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
            Set currManager = Managers(currManagerEmail)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If currManager Is Nothing Then
            Set currManager = New Manager
            currManager.ManagerEmail = currManagerEmail
            Managers.Add currManager, Key:=currManager.ManagerEmail
        End If
        Dim currClient As Client
        Set currClient = New Client
        currClient.ClientID = currWS.Cells(currCell.Row, 1).Text 'assumes client ID is in column 1
        currManager.Clients.Add currClient, Key:=currClient.ClientID
    Next
End Sub
```

once you have the collection of managers just loop that to create your manager-specific email.

Since I used Usedrange.Rows.Count to set up the range to loop it should have worked ok without an additional check. However, since I don't have your actual data to be sure, you may need it. I don't have line numbers, so I don't know what line 51  refers to. To loop the Managers:

```
Sub LoopManagers()
    Dim currManager As Manager
    For Each currManager In Managers
        Debug.Print currManager.ManagerEmail
        Dim currClient As Client
        For Each currClient In currManager.Clients
            Debug.Print currClient.ClientID
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

You will need to adapt what I've provided to create your emails. Work on it. If you need more help post what you tried and describe what problems you have.

Comment: You code works great to create the collection. Is is acurately printing manager and its sets of clients. 
However, I couldn't find a way to organize and send this set of clients via e-mail.
I can get the recipient of the e-mail for each currManager.ManagerEmail, but that is as far as I get.
My goal is to insert on an .HTMLBody the exactly lines of the sheets belonging to the manager, but I have no clue on how to accomplish that.
Could you help me some more?
[Module 1 has your code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wly4ZXIVM0Xt5GHimRgRw0-B6iJuSJcN/view?usp=sharing)